# how can i find text search in an array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
 {
    "_id":objectId(23651478),
    "name":"Tomatos"
    "array":[
             {"title":"Vegetables"}
            ]
    "description":"Vegitables are good to health"
 },
 {
    "_id":objectId(45761244),
    "name":"Apples"
    "array":[
             {"title":"Fruits"}
            ]
    "description":"Fruits are good to health, vegitables are also good to health"
 },
 {
    "_id":objectId(45761244),
    "name":"Apples"
    "array":[
             {"title":"Vegetables-home-made"}
            ]
    "description":"Fruits are good to health, vegitables are also good to health"
 }
```

Above is my mongo schema modal for my project requirement. When I want to search for vegetables only, vegetable name should have to come. If I search for both vegetables and fruits, both names ie., Tomato and Apple should have to come.

I used `"$in"` operator like this

```
{"array":{$in:[{"title":"Vegetables"},{"title":"Fruits"}]}}
```

It is giving only documents that have the title `Vegetables` and not the `Vegetables-Home-made`. For that I tried to use `$elemMatch`

```
 {"array":{$elemMatch:[{"title":"Vegetables"},{"title":"Fruits"}]}}
```

But when we search for multiples ie., `Vegetables` and `Fruits` in elemMatch, it is giving an error, I want a text search in a array for particular title key only ie.,

```
{"array":{$text:{:$search:[{"title":"Vegetables"},{"title":"Fruits"}]}}}
```

Comment: you can use regular expression $regex or $text. try this :  {"array":{$in:[{"title": { $regex:{/Vegetables/}}]}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is what you want:

**you can use regular expression within $in operator like this :**

```
{array: { $elemMatch: { title: { $in: [/Vegetables/, /Fruits/] }}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The general text search in MongoDB looks like that:

```
db.collectionName.find( { $text: { $search: "Vegetables" } } )
```

Please check the search text you are running the word **Vegetables** contains a spelling error in it:

```
{"array":{$text:{:$search:[{"title":"Vegitables"},{"title":"Fruits"}]}}}
```

Comment: This requires a text index.